# Is It Possible word automation in Openoffice

Tags: c#, openoffice.org

I have code in `C#` for word automation in `MS-office`.But I want word automation in `openoffice` using C#. so Is it possible through openoffice? I want to read ,write and saveAs .doc file programatically in `openoffice` using `C#`
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no,

Word is not part of Open Office, so how would that work?

You can however [automate Writer](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/CLI/CLI_Language_Binding) but, it has a different model so much of you code would have to be re-written.

---

If Open Office were to expose a compatible API I think that would raise some interesting  Copyright and Intellectual Property issues but, I'm no lawyer. However, I'm not extolling the benefits of either product or API, they are just different.

Comment: I want `.doc` file to be read or write in `openoffice` so Is there any way to do with C#

Comment: start here http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/CLI/Writing_Client_Programs

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You must setup. OpenOffice, OpenOffice SDK, when the SDK is installed, you must run `setsdkenv_windows.bat` in the SDK folder, then it will require another components, you must install just 3 or 4 from here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html.

The sample for CALC could be in a path like C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3\Basis\sdk\examples\CLI\CSharp\Spreadsheet

The samples for Writer are just online, just now I need the samples for Impress, but the automation with the automation for CALC is 10/10